# CSS - indent list on soft line wrap to character position

Tags: css

I have a list like so:

```
<ol>
<li>2017 &mdash; Lorem ipsum blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.
<li>2018 &mdash; Lorem ipsum blah.
</ol>
```

This currently displays like this:

```
* 2017 — Lorem ipsum blah blah blah blah 
  blah blah blah blah blah.
* 2018 - Lorem ipsum blah.
```

What I’m after is for it to wrap like this:

```
* 2017 — Lorem ipsum blah blah blah blah 
         blah blah blah blah blah.
* 2018 - Lorem ipsum blah.
```

In QuarkXPress you can enter a special hidden character that forces the indenting of all lines of text from that point to the next paragraph return. (In the example above this special hidden character would go before the “L”.) This is what I’m after in CSS — does such a thing exist?

Comment: I don't know if there's a simple CSS way of doing it, you may be able to hack it by dividing the li contents into two divs, displayed inline-block.  Put the "year - " in one, and the text in the other.  Undoubtedly there's a better way to do it though.

Comment: I was trying to avoid a table or div based solution, as it’s a list of items and I’d like to keep it one. (Though I suppose it could be argued a table might be right too, but it seems more list-like to me.) Thank you for your suggestion though. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pseudo element and counter to achieve this:

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: section 2016;
  list-style:none;
}
ol li {
  display:flex;
}

li::before {
  counter-increment: section; 
  content: counter(section) " — "; 
  margin-right:5px;
  flex-shrink:0;
}
```

```html
<ol>
<li>Lorem ipsum blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum blah.</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. Does it work with screen readers etc do you know?

Comment: @RaspberryLime Ah, for screen reader the 2017/2018 won't be avaible since it's not a html content but CSS. It's also not available for selection, try to select all the text and you will see

Comment: That’s a real shame. I’d got it working right visually too (the list is actually much longer, with some years with no entries and others with multiple entries).